# System.Dynamic.Linq.Core + PostreSql call date_part function

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dynamic-linq-core

Hi to all and Sorry for my bad English!

I'm doing some tests with Entity Framework Core 5 + Postgre + [dynamic linq core](https://dynamic-linq.net/)

My DataContext is defined like this:

```
 public class Context: DbContext {

    public DbSet<Models.Anagrafica> Anagrafiche {get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(@"Host=XYZ;Database=XYZ;Username=XYZ;Password=XYZ");
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Anagrafica>().ToTable("Anagrafiche");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Anagrafica>().Property(p => p.Id)HasColumnName("id");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Anagrafica>().Property(p => p.RagioneSociale).HasColumnName ("ragionesociale");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Anagrafica>().Property(p => p.DataAttivazione).HasColumnName("dataattivazione");
        base.OnModelCreating (modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

The entity Anagrafica is defined as follows:

```
public class Anagrafica {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RagioneSociale { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataAttivazione { get; set; }
}
```

Question:
Is it possible to use the date_part function in the where?

If I run the code

```
var data =  context.Anagrafiche.Where("date_part(\"week\", dataattivazione) = @0",1).ToList();
```

I get the error message

System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Exceptions.ParseException: 'No applicable method 'date_part' exists in type 'Anagrafica''

Is it possible to use database functions and/or UDF in Dynamic Linq?
If it is possible to do it what am I wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: No.  It would be Where(x => DataAttivazione.DayOfWeek == 1) A week starts on Sunday being zero and Monday being one.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng for the reply.
My idea was to concatenate the query and pass a string and parameters to the where. In your example, for which I thank you, you use an expression.

Comment: You cannot use string unless you parse the string to an integer.  The DayOfWeek in DateTime is an integer.

Comment: Thanks again @jdweng. I understand that DayOfWeek is a number and should be converted (I haven't done this test yet). But the question remains: can I call Postgre functions from Dynamic.Linq.Core using a string? for example: context.Anagrafiche.Where ("NAME_FUNCTION_POSTGRE () = @ 0", "VALUE")

Comment: No.  You have a dbContext and the syntax has to be c# compatible.

Comment: Thanks jdweng. Using Dynamic linq core (not "pure linq") you can write where clauses using a string and an array of parameters. From documentation:  list = customers
      .Where("Name.Contains(@0)","ZZZ Projects")
      .ToList()